# loading icon during reading sql and then chart

Tags: asp.net, database, loading

i have another problem again! I have to create a loading icon during the program is loading from ms sql and after the reading, a chart should be shown, but the icon ist not showing during the process, so I can't know if the process is finished or not.

```
<head runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})

</script>
```

and in body:

```
<body>
<div class="loader">


<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="page-shadow">
    .
    .
    .
    .
</form>
</div>
```

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider reading your database via web service method then call that service with jQuery Ajax. check this example http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Loading-Busy-Indicator-Spinner-with-Overlay-with-jQuery-AJAX-example.aspx

Comment: in my project, it's not able to do it with ajax, any solution without ajax?